# Use Python to iterate through a list of date range and append to a set of data in csv

Tags: python, csv

Need help with appending a date from a list (range of dates) to a set of data in csv.

I am able to create a range of dates. Then use csv reader to go through csv. But I am stuck on how to append a date from the list and keep repeating till the last date (see below for desired output).

**CSV Data**

```
AsofDate,Account Number,Security ID,Market Value,Market Value Currency,Security Type Code,Weight
08/01/16,Account 1,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/01/16,Account 1,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/01/16,Account 2,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/01/16,Account 2,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/01/16,Account 3,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/01/16,Account 3,111,2000,USD,FC,5
```

**Python Code:**

```
import sys

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("08/01/2016", "%m/%d/%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("08/31/2016", "%m/%d/%Y")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

date_list = []

for date in date_generated:
    date_list.append(date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"));
#     print date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print date_list

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

**Desired Output**

```
AsofDate,Account Number,Security ID,Market Value,Market Value Currency,Security Type Code,Weight
08/01/16,Account 1,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/01/16,Account 1,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/01/16,Account 2,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/01/16,Account 2,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/01/16,Account 3,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/01/16,Account 3,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/02/16,Account 1,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/02/16,Account 1,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/02/16,Account 2,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/02/16,Account 2,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/02/16,Account 3,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/02/16,Account 3,111,2000,USD,FC,5
...
08/31/16,Account 1,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/31/16,Account 1,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/31/16,Account 2,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/31/16,Account 2,111,2000,USD,FC,5
08/31/16,Account 3,123,2000,USD,E,5
08/31/16,Account 3,111,2000,USD,FC,5
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the dates - 1) are you wanting to take the csv file and compute all the unique dates from `test.csv` ? 2) grab data from `test.csv` between the two dates? In either case you should use `pandas` module as this is really easy with that.

Comment: @Chinny84 unfortunately, can't use panda because in my server I can't import a module. More or so 2. Grab data from csv and create a new set of the same data by appending a new date from the list.

Comment: I am probably being a little dense - but how is the `test.csv` any different to `Final Output`?

Comment: @Chinny84 I am only sharing a small chunk of data. The goal is to take the existing data (test.csv) and clone that data for a different date. I have to append two years worth of dates (about 730 days). It wouldn't be ideal for me to do this in csv. So writing an automation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't fully understand your question so I deleted my previous answer because it was wrong.  Hopefully this is what you want.

Get the rows as dictionaries

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    rows = [row for row in reader]
```

Iterate over the dates and the rows, *substituting* the date in each row, then write it to a file.

```
with open('new.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for date in date_list:
        for row in rows:
            row['AsofDate'] = date
            writer.writerow(row)
```